# lotus notes calculate total time/days for view entries

Tags: lotus-notes

There is view listing a certain number of documents having as view selection a form. A column ( `Style = Date/Time` displaying `Time` ) has the formula: `time_1`. The next column is displaying: `time_2`.

with other words:

`time_1` - the time the user was at work.

`time_2` - the time the user must be at work ( let's say  08:00 hours ).

There is a view action button:

```
t1:=@DbColumn("Notes":"NoCache";"server/Company":"Name.nsf";"vwSearchResult";6);
total1:= @Sum(@ToNumber(t1)) ;
t2:=@DbColumn("Notes":"NoCache";"server/Company":"Name.nsf";"vwSearchResult";7);
total2:= @Sum(@ToNumber(t2)) ;

zile:=(total1-total2)/8; // 8 - is the minimun number of hours / day. " I must be at work minimum 8 hours "

@Prompt([Ok];"Time at work";@Text(total1));
@Prompt([Ok];"expected time";@Text(total2));
@Prompt([Ok];"Additional time - in days ";@Text(zile))
```

Just the 2nd Prompt is calculated correctly. The 1st prompt result is an integer number, and of course, implicitly the 3rd prompt is not displaying the result correctly.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure your @Sum(@ToNumber(t1)) is calculating valide numbers? Why don't you mark your column as number?

Comment: Because the respective column is displaying "08:00" as Time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your formula to

```
t1:=@DbColumn("Notes":"NoCache";"server/Company":"Name.nsf";"vwSearchResult";6);
total1:= @Sum(t1 - [00:00]) / 3600;
t2:=@DbColumn("Notes":"NoCache";"server/Company":"Name.nsf";"vwSearchResult";7);
total2:= @Sum(t2 - [00:00]) / 3600;
```

You can't convert a time value to a number with @ToNumber. Instead, calculate the difference between your time and 00:00. This gives you the number of seconds of your time.

Divide this by 3600 and you get the hours.

Comment: Make sure that your column values are all filled with a time value. Change the *column formula* to `@If(YourTimeField = ""; [00:00]; @ToTime(YourTimeField))` to make this sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to insert a column to the view which calculates the difference between time_1 and time_2.

Your @DbColum  will now run on the new column ans calculates the difference.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how the column formula will look?

Comment: (time_1 - time_2)/60 will return the diefference in minutes

Comment: And the style for the column will be? I'm getting: error: incorrect  data type ...

Comment: Its General (default)

Comment: Check if both fields shown in columns are date/time fields and if you have gut the braces in the formula of the result column